# Function notation?

Tags: calculus, functions, notation

Sorry for the trivial question.
Say that I have two functions $g$ (differentiable) and $e$ from some interval $J$ to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Is there any difference in either writing:
$$ \forall t \in J \colon \; g'(t) \cdot (g(t) \times e(t)) = 0,$$ or, more succinctly:
$$ g' \cdot (g \times e) = 0$$
?

Comment: If $\cdot$ is also the multiplication (ie: $\cdot =\times$) then, yes it's the same.

Comment: Nope, the first is a dot, the second is the cross product - I forgot to write they are vector valued

Comment: Both are acceptable.  It's the usual trade-off between brevity and being explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second notation is widely accepted, and is usually assumed to mean exactly the first statement that you wrote. So yes, I would say that you are allowed to write
$$g'\cdot(g\times e) = 0.$$